# correct (React/MaterialUI) method of placing sort icons under each other in a table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using the following code in a `tsx` component. I am not yet familiar with the [correct layout options](https://material-ui.com/layout/grid/).
I have a [working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mnjnl6xzy).

```
import React from "react";
import { ArrowDropUp, ArrowDropDown } from "@material-ui/icons";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

function SvgMaterialIcons(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            TITLE <ArrowDropUp /> <ArrowDropDown />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  );
}
```

What layout component should I use from material.ui to align the sort icons underneath each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a nasty rabit hole with styling the icons to look as pleased. why not look at this [Sort icon](https://materialdesignicons.com/icon/menu-swap-outline). It might work for you and save you time.